# Missing capital G in 'got a question about the site itself?' banner

Tags: bug, user-interface

[image: Read the top banner]

The *'got a question about the site itself?'* banner should have the G in got be capital.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more of a grammatical error than a "bug".

If we care about grammar, instead of "Got a question about the site?" I think it would be better to say "Do you have a question about the site?".

I agree with you, starting sentences without capital letters does not look very professional in the eyes of some viewers, including you and me.

Comment: Being that a professional site should have basic grammar on the major displayed things, I would call it a bug, albeit perhaps one that wont be fixed

Answer (score 7):

Bug or not, this is something that I agree should be changed. It's been reported on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376710/622284), which is considered the "global" meta, in the form of a feature request. The request also has some other objective improvements to the wording/format, so I'd say rallying behind it is our best path forward to getting a change for this field.

A community manager, V2Blast, commented:

> I suspect this banner message basically hasn't been changed in ages, so the formatting hasn't been updated to be in line with the [Stacks guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/) yet.

Which says to me that this simply needs to triaged by the dev team.